# Angular express.js CORS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am using express 4.1.0, and angular 1.2.12.

My client-code looks like this:

```
$http.get(data_url + '/stickers.json')
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // do stuff
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(status, config);
});
```

I have done all the correct express stuff, as far as I can tell:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept');
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/webroot'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

I also tried [cors](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors) module.

I am running my client-app on localhost, port 8000. The remote file is on heroku.

In all cases, I get this error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<URL>/stickers.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I access `http://<URL>/stickers.json` directly and look at returned headers, I see these:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

**Update:**

If you'd like to look at it, I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/konsumer/pen/JHAoG), and a new heroku app with above server code.

Weirdly, it works fine, so now I am really confused. I think it must be express, because it stops working when I swap the URLs.

**Update 2:**

If I run the codepen with the URL from localhost running the original code, it also works.  It must be something funny with heroku.

Comment: Problem description is OK, can you please also state a clear question that can be answered?

Comment: Question seems clear enough to me

Comment: Seems clear to me, too, but if not: "What is wrong with my CORS setup, and why does it not work?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!  it needs to be `http://*.herokuapp.com/`, or it redirects. I was using *.heroku.com.